# Breaking up and styling PHP math equation

Tags: php

How do I put a span around each character?

```
<span>1</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>9</span>

if ($row['make'] == "Hyundai" && $row['mileage'] <= "50000" && date("Y")-5 < $year) {
$remaining = 50000 - $row['mileage'];}
```

Comment: In your example you have put as `<span>` around each character...trick question? Maybe a bit more clear would be helpful.

Comment: The spans are only there to show what I was attempting to do. The 13569 is the $remaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were talking about not quite sure because what you said doesn't explain a whole lot but here you go

```
<?php

if ($row['make'] == "Hyundai" && $row['mileage'] <= "50000" && date("Y")-5 < $year) {
    $remaining = 50000 - $row['mileage'];
}
$Split = str_split($remaining);
$spannedArray = array();
foreach ($Split as $char) {
    $newChar = "<span>".$char."</span>";
    array_push($spannedArray, $newChar);
}
foreach ($spannedArray as $spannedChar) {
    echo($spannedChar);
}
?>
```

Comment: @BradGuy np thank you for the response have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen() and substr() to count the individual characters and append the tags to each in a loop.

```
$remaining = 12345;
$length = strlen($test);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo '<span>' . substr($remaining, $i, 1) . '</span>';
}
```